# concurrent modification exception with iterator

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, concurrency, iterator

I'm fairly new to java and I'm essentially writing a keylogger and having it write to file at regular intervals. Everytime a user presses a key it instantiates a NativeKeyEvent which invokes 'paramString()' and adds the information as a string to the arraylist below...

```
public static ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();

public synchronized String paramString() {
    StringBuilder param = new StringBuilder(255);
    // other code
    stringArray.add(param.toString());
}
```

Then at each interval the string array is passed across and is written to file in the TimerTask thread below...

```
public class SaveToArrayAndWriteTask extends TimerTask {

private ArrayList<String> anotherArray = NativeKeyEvent.stringArray;
private static String str;

   @Override
   public synchronized void run() {
     openFile();
     writeToFile(anotherArray);
     closeFile();
   }

   private static synchronized void writeToFile(ArrayList<String> localArray) {

    Iterator<String> iterator = localArray.iterator();
    try {
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            str = iterator.next().toString();
            output.format("%s\n", str);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The line 'str = iterator.next().toString();' then throws an exception if it attempts to iterate through the arraylist to write it to file while the program is recording / adding another key stroke. I thought by putting stringArray (which is being modified) into anotherArray and passing it as an argument would stop this from happening. As you can see I've tried using the synchronized keyword and I've also tried putting it into another thread and have read various other posts on stackoverflow but to no avail.

What would be the best way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't making a copy of the ArrayList, you are just making another reference to the same ArrayList.

```
private ArrayList<String> anotherArray = NativeKeyEvent.stringArray;
```

Should be something like:

```
private ArrayList<String> copy = new ArrayList<>(NativeKeyEvent.stringArray);
```

This will create a *new* ArrayList with the same elements as `NativeKeyEvent.stringArray`.

I would recommend using a getter instead of exposing `stringArray` as a public variable. The getter should make a copy of the `stringArray` and return that instead. That way any consumer of `stringArray` will operate on a copy and won't have the possibility of modifying the list.

Comment: Excellent that solved the issue completely. And I've make that first arraylist private. Not making a new arraylist seems like a stupid mistake now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> I thought by putting stringArray (which is being modified) into anotherArray

```
private ArrayList<String> anotherArray = NativeKeyEvent.stringArray;
```

Is not creating a new ArrayList. anotherArray is still referencing the same object.
You need to create a new ArrayList that contains the elements of stringArray.

```
private ArrayList<String> anotherArray = new ArrayList<>(NativeKeyEvent.stringArray);
```

Comment: Sorted thanks! Overlooking creating a new arraylist, rookie mistake! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if you modify a collection while iterating over it, you'll get a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

You have two choices:

The hard way: synchronize access to the list so other threads block while you're iterating

The easy way: Use the [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) list implementation from the [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) package, which does all the hard work for you

```
public static ArrayList<String> stringArray = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>();
```

That's it. Nothing more needed, and you can remove all synchronization.

Comment: Thanks I'll be sure to tidy that up!